# Canvas image generation using fabric

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

```
var front = document.getElementById("tcanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
```

i have used above code for exporting image but i am getting below error :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Answer (score 0):

A Canvas is "tainted" if anything in the canvas is retrieved from a foregin origin.

The section on the [limitations](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Documentation#limitations) in the documentation of html2canvas says: everything that should be rendered needs to be in the same origin.

The origin is basically the left-hand part of the URL:

```
http://subdomain.domain.tld/somedocument.html
^         ORIGIN          ^
```

You need to make sure everything you wan to render has the same origin (or left-hand part).